# Kubernetes on AWS: Preserving Client IP with nginx-ingress + cert-manager

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, amazon-eks

We have setup Kubernetes with `nginx-ingress` combined with `cert-manager` to automatically obtain and use SSL certificates for ingress domains using LetsEncrypt using this guide: https://medium.com/@maninder.bindra/auto-provisioning-of-letsencrypt-tls-certificates-for-kubernetes-services-deployed-to-an-aks-52fd437b06b0. The result is that each Ingress defines its own SSL certificate that is automatically provisioned by `cert-manager`.

This all works well but for one problem, the source IP address of the traffic is lost to applications in Pods.

There is an annotation that is advised to use to apply to the `nginx-ingress` controller service `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: '*'`. This has the effect of preserving source IP addresses. However, doing it breaks SSL:

```
An error occurred during a connection to {my.domain.com}. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

My head is starting to spin. Does anyone know of any approaches to this (it seems to me that this would be a common requirement)?

Ingress configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-http-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.host.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-http-service
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "my.host.com"
    secretName: malcolmqa-tls
```

Comment: Can you share your ingress resource configuration?

Comment: Ingress configuration added. Incidentally I moved the whole cluster to GCE and have managed to achieve what I wanted without trouble (and the entire experience was a whole less unpleasant).

In GCE, adding `controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local` to the Helm install/upgrade command for `stable/nginx-ingress` did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dom_watson mentioned in the comments, adding parameter `controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local` to Helm install configuration solved the issue due to the fact that `Local` value preserves the client source IP, thus the network traffic will reach target Pod in Kubernetes cluster. Find more information in the official Kubernetes [guidelines](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip).

Answer (score -1):

```
helm upgrade my-nginx stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true --set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local
```